# Refresh screen data (START-OF-SELECTION)

Tags: abap, alv

I'm developing a report with multiple ALVs.
In START-OF-SELECTION I have:

1) data selection

2) ALV display cl_salv_hierseq_table

The lines can be selected through checkbox. When a button is pressed, some tables in DB are updated. After this processing, I have to return to point 2,
BUT the data on the screen has to be updated (point 1). How I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I would select the same data again, and re-display it.  If you know what line of data is changed, you can "select single" in order to save processing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the `REFRESH` method of the class.

Comment: Yes, this was I needed :) Thank you